# Antlr4 parse list of expression

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to parse an input of a list of items.

An item can be a number, a function `(foo(a, b))`, or a combination: `1+2`, `(foo(a,b))-10`

Here is a part of my grammar file:

```
listExpr: listItem+;

listItem 
   : Minus listItem
   | listItem ( Plus | Minus ) listItem
   | Number 
   | ParenData
   ;

Minus: '-';
Plus: '+';
ParenData: '(' (ParenData | ~[()] )* ')';
Number: INT | FLOAT;

fragment FLOAT: DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT*;
fragment INT: DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

WS: [ ,\t] -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

Input: `1.1 (foo(a, b)+bar(c, d)) -2 1-2 (foo(a, b))-4 -12`

I want to have list of `listItem` as: `1.1` `(foo(a, b)+bar(c, d))` `-2` `1-2` `(foo(a, b))-4` `-12`

Currently get: `1.1` `(foo(a, b)+bar(c, d))-2` `1-2` `(foo(a, b))-4-12`

I am having a hard time distinguish the `-2` as a negative number, or as a part of an item in `1-2`.
Are there any way that can recognize the negative number in the lexer layer? In this case, if there is a number, I want to check whether there are `space` and `-` before it.

Meantime, I still want to keep the WhiteSpace out of parser rule.

Comment: Why do you want `(foo(a, b)+bar(c, d))` and `-2` to be separate expressions, but include the `-4` in `(foo(a, b))-4`?

Comment: I use `white space` as delimiter, `-2` should be treated as an expression since there is a whitespace before it, while `-4` is a part of `(foo(a, b))-4`.

Comment: OK, if the white space is a delimiter, it must be "promoted" as a real token so that you can do `listItem (WS listItem)*`. I know you said you wanted to keep it out of the parser, but if it has a special meaning, you can't hide it.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Bart for the pointer!